# Rails 3.2.13 app fails after shared host Mysql update

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two Rails 3.2.13 apps on Justhost server.

Recently they updated Mysql to Mysql2, after that I got errors:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
```

And specific:

```
Error message:
(Mysql2::Error)
```

My **setup**:

bundle show mysql turns : `/home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/ecotechno/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/mysql2-0.3.16`

In **database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
 # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Bassicaly when I contacted support they said they can't help me.

Full backtrace of error :

```
0   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/client.rb  24  in `initialize_ext'
1   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/client.rb  24  in `initialize'
2   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb 16  in `new'
3   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb 16  in `mysql2_connection'
4   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   315 in `new_connection'
5   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   325 in `checkout_new_connection'
6   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   247 in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
7   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   242 in `loop'
8   /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   242 in `block in checkout'
9   /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/monitor.rb    211 in `mon_synchronize'
10  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   239 in `checkout'
11  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   102 in `block in connection'
12  /usr/lib64/ruby/1.9.3/monitor.rb    211 in `mon_synchronize'
13  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   101 in `connection'
14  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb   410 in `retrieve_connection'
15  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  171 in `retrieve_connection'
16  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb  145 in `connection'
17  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb   310 in `clear_cache!'
18  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/railtie.rb    103 in `block (2 levels) in '
19  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb    418 in `_run__4470304995410275411__prepare__777669663684257344__callbacks'
20  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb    405 in `__run_callback'
21  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb    385 in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
22  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb    81  in `run_callbacks'
23  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb    74  in `prepare!'
24  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.16/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb    48  in `prepare!'
25  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb   47  in `block in '
26  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `instance_exec'
27  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb  30  in `run'
28  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb  55  in `block in run_initializers'
29  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `each'
30  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/initializable.rb  54  in `run_initializers'
31  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/application.rb    136 in `initialize!'
32  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb   30  in `method_missing'
33  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/config/environment.rb 10  in `'
34  config.ru   3   in `require'
35  config.ru   3   in `block in
'
36  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `instance_eval'
37  /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb  51  in `initialize'
38  config.ru   1   in `new'
39  config.ru   1   in `
'
40  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `eval'
41  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  225 in `load_rack_app'
42  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  157 in `block in initialize_server'
43  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 563 in `report_app_init_status'
44  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  154 in `initialize_server'
45  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   204 in `start_synchronously'
46  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   180 in `start'
47  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb  129 in `start'
48  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 253 in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
49  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    132 in `lookup_or_add'
50  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 246 in `block in spawn_rack_application'
51  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    82  in `block in synchronize'
52      prelude>    10:in `synchronize'
53  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb    79  in `synchronize'
54  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 244 in `spawn_rack_application'
55  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 137 in `spawn_application'
56  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb 275 in `handle_spawn_application'
57  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   357 in `server_main_loop'
58  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb   206 in `start_synchronously'
59  /etc/httpd/modules/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server  99  in `
```

In application logs :

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I checked databases are present. Users with passwords are valid.

I tested if console works. Yes it works.

```
rails console production
```

I was able to create new record and also update existing one!

This makes me think what is wrong then ? If just for webservice database is not working ?

So from where this problem comes ?

Any tip would be great.
thanks

Comment: if you're previously using mysql, and the Gemfile was updated to use mysql2, did you also update your `config/database.yml` to use mysql2?

Comment: @jvnill I forgot to mention before Justhost made update everything worked with gem 'mysql2', but after this update I havent changed code a bit.

Comment: maybe you just have to reinstall the mysql2 gem. uninstall all versions of the `mysql2` gem and then run `bundle`.

Comment: @jvnill Thanks. I tried this. No change. Maybe I just need to change my database? To like PostgreSQL that is only one I can choose other than Mysql .

Comment: if that is an option for you, then go for it, but for other developers out there who visit this question looking for answers, it would be nice to know what exactly caused the issue.

Comment: @jvnill Hosting company updated Mysql to Mysql2 that is cause of the problem. I couldn't dig in deeper because my apps was already down for 3 days. It is very bad for business.

Comment: Hey Edgars, what did you eventually end up doing?

Comment: @MickJuice Hey. I changed my database to PostgreSQL, that was only option.Now everything works. Poor support from Justhost.com...

Comment: Ugh yea I'm having issues too. Support told me to revert to 0.3.16 but there is still a connection issue. I'm going to try a little bit more with mysql but might just switch to Sqlite as my app is very database non-intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this easily by reverting to mysql, and adding the port number 3306 to my database.yml
*for the record my app is on shared hosting on Bluehost.

previous database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
database: my_db
encoding: utf8
username: my_username
password: my_password
host: localhost
reconnect: true
```

current database.yml:

```
development:
adapter: mysql
database: my_db
encoding: utf8
username: my_username
password: my_password
host: 127.0.0.1
reconnect: true
socket: mysql
port: 3306
```

Comment: I was having many mysql failures, so took the plunge and updated my app to Rails4.1. (it only took a few hours to do so!) I also locked the mysql2 gem at v3.0.16 (which bluehost recommended). one more thing, i added: socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock to my database.yml. :)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Although with host:localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, and also with the socket mentioned /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.